# how to rename files using php rename function when file name contains '/' character?

Tags: php, file-rename

I tried to use the rename() in php but the problem is i cant rename my files because the file name contains '/' and thus,it is treated as a part of the url.

Here's my code snippet:

```
rename("/home/yashshah/Desktop/check","/home/yashshah/Desktop/a/b");
```

I want to rename my `"check"` file as `"a/b"` but cant do so.
I have also tried using encoding but then the file is renamed to `a%2Fb`(since %2F stands for '/') instead of `"a/b"`.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: i think '/ 'is allow in rename but please check /a/b folder available in your Desktop directory

Comment: No...'/' will be understood as a file path extension instead of name!

Comment: yes exactly so you must have to /a/b directory into your Desktop directory

Comment: I dont want to have any a/b directory...I want to rename it to a/b...

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
 $file['name'] = str_replace("/", "%2F" , $file['name']);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I get your point but how I can i get the file name as input?I mean on executing,the file name should be replaced as desired.The replaced changes should be reflected in the file name simultaneously.